# Why does interrupt() interrupt two threads in quick succession?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I want to start a thread, interrupt it and start a new thread. The Problem is, that this doesn't really work. The first thread starts and gets interrupted, but the following thread gets interrupted before it even can start. So interrupt() interrupts the old and the new thread. The output looks like this:

```
run()-method starts
Thread Counter:0
Thread Counter:1
Thread Counter:2
Thread Counter:3
Thread Counter:4
Thread Counter:5
Thread Counter:6
8 seconds are over 
Thread is not null 
Thread will be interrupted now
catch
run()-method starts
catch
8 seconds are over 
Thread is not null 
Thread will be interrupted now
....
```

You can see that the thread starts the first time. Then the thread gets interrupted and 'catch' is called. So far, so good. After this, the next thread is going to start, but this time the thread gets interrupted immediately and 'catch' is called right after 'run()-method starts'.

So, I can't figure out why this is happening. I don't want two threads being interrupted in quick succession.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyRunnable {
    static Thread myThread; 
    static boolean stop;
    static Runnable myRunny = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run()-method starts");
            try {
                int j = 0;
                while (!stop) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Thread Counter:"+j); 
                    j++;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("catch");
                myThread.interrupt();
            }
        };
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        myThread = null;

        while(true) {
            stop = false;
            if(myThread != null) {
                System.out.println("Thread is not null ");
                System.out.println("Thread will be interrupted now");       
                myThread.interrupt();
            }

            myThread = new Thread(myRunny);
            myThread.start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(8000);
                System.out.print("8 seconds are over "+ "\n");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you called it from the catch block. Why did you do that?

Comment: @EJP I searched for examples that show how to stop threads. So I found one, in which the thread got interrupted by calling interrupt() in the catch-block....

Link: http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_14_003.htm#mj4193c6da30b5a3e9d41c167ec04d571f

Comment: But you didn't copy your source accurately. That code re-interrupts *itself* for some reason. Your code interrupts the *next* thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (InterruptedException e) {
     System.out.println("catch");
     myThread.interrupt();
}
```

myThread field is replaced with new reference before calling myThread.interrupt(), so you interrupt the new thread!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a novice at threads and didn't understand what was happening. Now I understand and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> So interrupt() interrupts the old and the new thread.

Your diagnosis is incorrect.  A call to Thread.interrupt will interrupt one thread once.

What your example is doing is interrupting one thread, and that thread is catching `InterruptedException` and interrupting a second thread in the exception handler.  Two *calls* to `interrupt` are being made in quick succession on *different* threads.

> I don't want two threads being interrupted in quick succession.

Well change

```
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("catch");
            myThread.interrupt();
        }
```

to

```
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("catch");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm a beginner and really didn't understand the problem. Now I do. I fixed the code like you suggested, it works!